# How do I get only the extension of a file when writing a shell command for a context menu

Tags: windows, command-line

For example if type `cmd.exe echo %1` it shows the filename and extension of the selected file. But what I want to do is just get the extension of the selected file by itself.

Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cmd.exe echo %~x1`

```
%*      return the remainder of the command line starting at the first command line   argument (in Windows NT 4, %* also includes all leading spaces)
%~dn    return the drive letter of %n (n can range from 0 to 9) if %n is a valid path or file name (no UNC)  
%~pn    return the directory of %n if %n is a valid path or file name (no UNC)  
%~nn    return the file name only of %n if %n is a valid file name  
%~xn    return the file extension only of %n if %n is a valid file name  
%~fn    return the fully qualified path of %n if %n is a valid file name or directory
```

[Source](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php)

Comment: Maybe others want to know *how* you got it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Powershell easily, using the Extension attribute.

One example (Although many more methods to accomplish this are possible:

```
Get-ChildItem | select Extension
```

And in cmd.exe:

```
for %i in (*.*) do echo "%~xi"
```

Comment: added DIR command

Comment: Sorry I type the wrong command is " cmd.exe echo %1" 
and explaining again  what i want is get only the extension of  any file I select, and not for a specific extension,for all extensions.

"for example if type cmd.exe echo %1 ,it shows the filename and extension of the selected file"

I want to create a context menu option  with a similar option but i need to print only the extension

Comment: Alright, updated with that in mind.